# Props and potential uses

Tags: props, sound-effects, library

This thread could be a collection of props and associated ideas for when:

- you have props you don't know what to do with
- you need a sound you don't know how to prop up (is that even a term?)

**Ideally**, one prop would be discussed per post and the discussion of a particular prop would take place in the form of comments to the prop's post.

Answer (score 1):

I have a bag of empty film canisters (possibly a few hundreds) like this one:

[image]

Any ideas of what it could be used for? It kinda reminds me the LOTR beer caps...

SUGGESTIONS SO FAR:

- fill them with various grains, seeds...
- drop them
- throw them (attached to arrows)/fly-bys

Comment: OMG, there are only a bajillion uses! Fill them with sand, kitty litter, small ball bearings, uncooked beans, uncooked rice, pine nuts...it'll turn into a Vorpal Rattle Canister of Many Sounds +5. :-)

Comment: Drop them from a high place and record the impacts on the floor.  Do this with them empty and open, empty and closed, and filled with some of the stuff above.

Turn one into a ghetto hydrophone. http://www.instructables.com/id/Underwater-Microphone-Hydrophone/

Comment: Dry-ice bombs, too.

Comment: @Justin Cut the bottom of it off and slip one of them over a Schoeps capsule to create an interesting reflector of the sound and record different things with it and see how it sounds.

Comment: @Justin Cut one up and tie it to the end of a arrow and shoot the arrow and record it.

Comment: Fill with coke and Mentos. Boom!

Comment: A slight variation on the 'filling with various grains, seeds'...try filling half full and fire them off using a sling-shot. Record the capsules as they fly-by

Comment: Drill holes in the bottom of all of them, loosely screw them to two pieces of plywood. Perform footsteps for a battalion of little green army men.

Comment: Fill them with gasoline, like 20 of them and throw them in a metal container, light them on fire and remember to use safe clothing and a trashy pop filter.  Remember the telephone using two cups and string?  String many of them together and out put speakers or whatever if anything at all into them and record close mic or contact mic.